# How to stop graphical device window cutting off edges of plot()?

Tags: r, plot

I have a `mfrow=c(6,4)` plot and a special situation where I want each plot to be `mar=c(1,1,1,1)`. This makes it such that the `x-axis` and the `xlab` of the bottom 4 graphs get chopped off (even when exporting to `.eps`).

How do I stop `R` doing this? I've tried doing `postscript("test.eps",height=N)` where `N` is some real number that's larger than the default. This makes a lot of white space in the top and bottom of the `.eps` but the `x-axis` is still cut off.

So my question is; how do I get `plot()` to stop cutting off my `x-axis` and `xlab` given the constraint that I want the `mfrow` and `mar` described above? (I'm looking perhaps for some way to make the bottom of the device bigger such that the stuff I want isn't chopped off?).

Here's my plots:

```
postscript("test.eps")
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rnorm(100)

par(mfrow=c(6,4),mar=c(1,1,1,1))

for(i in 1:((6*4)))
{
    if(i <= (6*4)-4)
    {
    plot(y,x,xlab="",xaxt="n")
    }
    if(i > (6*4)-4)
    {
    plot(y,x,xlab="HELLO")
    }
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add an outer margin (`oma`) to not clip the tick labels, and plot the axis-label with `mtext` to get it closer than the default position.

```
postscript("test.eps")
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rnorm(100)

par(mfrow=c(6,4),mar=c(1,1,1,1), oma=c(3,1,0,0))

for(i in 1:((6*4)))
{
    if(i <= (6*4)-4)
    {
    plot(y,x,xlab="",xaxt="n")
    }
    if(i > (6*4)-4)
    {
    plot(y,x,xlab="")
    mtext("HELLO", 1, 2.5)
    }
}
dev.off()
```

[image]