# R figure being cropped

Tags: r, heatmap

Here's a bit of a basic question, you'd think R would automate this always. I'm making a heatmap (basic stuff, png() into heatmap.2() into dev.off()), and my row labels get cleaved off on the right hand side, along with a tiny part of the dendrogram on the left:

[image: there's supposed to be five numbers after the final letter of the labels]

Fiddling with the margins manually would eventually lead to a sensible output, but the problem is that this is part of an automated pipeline with biologist users in mind. Surely there's some automated way to do this, right? I mean, in RGui on OSX, a quick reshape of the figure window fixes the layout automatically, so it has to be possible. Thanks, and sorry to bother you.

**EDIT:** Procedure to reproduce this visualisation:

Input data:

```
Time,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48
CATMA1A23000,0.21129,0.48322,0.54234,0.93714,0.51816,0.11103,0.38304,0.97183,0.61381,-0.13775,0.32575,0.85221,0.1921,1.8692,0.4117,0.51977,0.74019,0.98932,0.023536,0.8849,0.75141,0.42846,0.03839,0.50295,0.38849,-0.95087,0.55017,-0.14813,0.79036,0.40978,-0.33048,0.81173,0.60585,0.014413,0.86586,0.063947,1.1195,0.25425,-0.090325,1.3035,0.90609,0.62866,0.83168,0.88655,0.4843,0.60098,0.26669,0.66605,0.78468,-0.76709,0.29615,-0.8911,0.5022,-0.93834,-0.065904,0.58003,0.41217,-0.99012,-0.032054,0.69119,1.1791,-0.0059458,0.81002,0.76421,1.302,0.77637,0.7824,1.192,-0.27005,-0.24698,1.8706,0.33513,0.38592,1.1987,0.48569,0.7104,2.4307,0.68148,0.11407,0.65619,0.94468,1.245,0.44146,0.71048,0.96389,1.7647,0.22729,0.96875,-0.2738,1.2975,2.0503,0.52507,2.282,1.0773,0.44489,0.22504
CATMA1A30870,3.9909,5.1844,5.2522,5.5482,5.665,5.4666,5.4456,5.5456,5.0014,5.5408,3.9324,3.9288,4.3624,3.0828,5.4821,5.1446,4.5638,4.6449,5.2604,4.2607,4.0942,3.9892,5.1361,3.8625,3.9454,5.3148,5.188,6.088,5.2085,5.3073,5.5652,4.8358,4.6111,4.9911,3.1497,4.3796,4.2456,3.9712,5.0998,5.4383,5.0908,4.5155,4.6486,5.1233,4.4259,4.7218,3.7928,4.0384,4.1085,6.2787,5.4937,5.9637,5.4085,5.188,5.3057,5.1963,4.3807,4.8352,3.9584,3.5859,3.8535,3.9755,4.5199,5.1093,5.3526,4.1214,4.5787,3.4499,4.1962,4.6929,4.3379,4.6376,4.4774,5.2341,5.3061,5.6769,3.6244,5.1073,4.543,4.9929,4.9341,3.9829,4.4304,4.0021,3.7498,4.2972,5.3338,4.8094,4.5766,5.5171,3.1207,5.0926,3.0253,4.351,4.351,4.5253
CATMA1A65800,0.65615,0.54186,0.93488,0.2205,0.38134,0.95061,0.60157,0.66508,0.83971,1.3625,0.9037,1.1606,1.0143,0.91896,1.3587,1.2468,1.0147,0.44113,1.5196,0.60232,0.52456,0.82557,0.43697,1.3253,0.78614,0.73697,1.0593,0.010271,0.59042,0.58544,0.38307,1.0372,1.071,0.21915,1.1779,0.97341,0.95672,0.92057,1.3866,1.3884,0.99241,1.0546,1.0215,1.0144,1.1606,1.2421,0.89549,0.56747,0.99347,1.0706,1.3403,0.48719,0.30759,1.0215,0.76474,0.87313,0.47597,1.5028,1.2201,1.7923,0.64299,1.3612,1.0079,0.64145,1.0969,0.90254,0.9109,0.85213,0.55241,0.63797,1.5373,0.45586,0.59624,0.5717,0.13919,-0.012128,2.7367,0.83577,0.13422,0.13908,0.32377,0.013345,-0.017209,0.47044,1.034,1.4932,1.0067,0.57515,1.1405,0.95364,3.0214,0.14601,2.1645,1.1704,0.45205,0.83406
CATMA1C71184,4.2879,2.7256,3.306,2.2375,2.6575,4.6438,4.3899,3.8518,5.3494,3.8049,5.4095,4.5437,3.4362,4.0983,2.5059,2.7275,3.9432,3.5177,4.266,4.6446,4.9338,3.5188,3.7903,4.4867,3.9692,3.3382,3.2898,3.4103,3.3025,4.1279,4.3532,5.0625,5.756,4.7799,5.0303,4.8974,3.8698,2.887,2.7541,2.7837,3.0665,4.0168,3.7507,4.6273,5.2384,3.7049,4.5843,3.97,2.7142,3.6205,3.5394,3.3561,3.2672,4.4467,5.2044,5.2177,3.8496,5.7881,4.7594,5.0395,2.8281,2.8751,2.8322,2.6873,1.8326,3.042,3.834,4.7844,3.1947,3.2571,4.0826,4.8398,3.8147,2.7439,2.846,2.64,2.8055,3.421,3.8495,4.9367,4.6413,3.5281,4.0636,3.7144,3.4468,2.3466,1.7452,2.3151,4.022,2.9211,3.89,3.7213,4.1856,3.3613,4.0891,4.2135
CATMA1C71776,-2.0266,-0.77692,-1.3279,-0.40422,-0.38614,-0.34387,-0.44277,0.99775,1.0748,0.17831,-0.14209,-0.98905,-0.88619,0.40548,-0.37731,0.18112,-0.80473,-0.26957,0.49049,0.25413,0.30341,0.20203,-1.0343,-0.17877,-0.46107,-1.202,-0.58841,-1.0995,-1.1079,-0.10977,0.29428,0.33363,0.35537,0.55571,-0.11074,-0.69584,-0.052035,-0.18207,-0.45321,-0.2778,-0.81074,-0.27129,0.087758,0.52214,0.33791,0.51601,-0.30863,0.14386,-0.2922,-0.21013,-0.73268,-1.1732,-0.36599,0.4731,1.0357,0.62377,0.8219,0.6029,-0.27195,1.0677,-0.48423,-0.57601,-0.43393,-2.0519,-0.67433,-0.44234,0.0078619,0.40677,-0.47102,-0.59971,0.30058,-0.4604,-0.56523,-3.3913,-0.52856,-0.54137,1.0418,-0.26115,0.21246,0.37858,0.38716,-0.86708,-0.41297,-0.21536,-0.06004,-0.48526,-1.2651,-0.52592,0.23757,-0.73376,1.0272,0.59383,0.65704,-0.017658,-0.44128,-0.30226
CATMA2A41800,1.5057,1.8357,2.7851,2.9125,2.6421,2.3881,2.4772,2.3367,2.2988,3.0073,2.7659,2.8454,2.5939,2.6327,2.6184,2.3415,3.3473,2.7683,1.1123,1.9614,1.8795,2.2335,2.9227,3.1536,2.6255,2.5264,2.3874,3.3196,1.8572,2.3446,2.3358,1.683,2.1742,2.8082,2.8634,2.8607,2.6755,3.2567,2.0726,3.0746,2.8984,2.5235,2.9399,2.5731,1.9196,2.9845,2.965,2.8055,1.1878,-0.6181,2.9552,2.7814,3.0701,-0.42372,2.5897,2.6331,1.7218,-0.70788,2.9578,1.1506,3.3772,1.6571,3.3166,3.5001,2.6541,2.5367,2.8643,2.1034,2.6389,1.8915,2.4861,3.2271,1.7718,2.7359,2.391,2.7223,1.1594,2.4025,1.1524,2.1405,2.253,2.4368,2.8053,2.2955,2.2877,2.7792,3.4115,3.2464,-0.37629,3.0582,1.682,2.0598,1.8747,2.0158,2.4714,2.1816
CATMA2C47274,2.2048,1.6574,0.96502,0.15092,0.5251,0.40351,0.90106,-0.12415,0.48846,0.03794,0.86292,0.27027,0.71848,1.8535,0.47188,-0.067504,0.68578,0.28113,0.17559,0.29659,0.067618,0.79368,-0.36732,0.80945,2.4297,1.3272,1.3741,0.005024,0.57369,0.6195,0.17845,1.3991,0.71594,-0.76358,0.74421,0.078431,0.97596,0.14151,-0.77085,0.64926,-0.24602,1.3478,0.49879,0.90549,0.78024,0.94685,0.023589,0.07446,1.3597,0.19311,1.1883,-0.20756,0.59042,0.031659,0.3591,1.1757,0.97314,-1.0133,0.92409,1.2264,-0.0095851,-0.47315,1.3107,1.3967,0.80332,0.5494,1.0394,1.4519,0.50253,-0.65282,1.5689,0.17996,1.5938,0.28124,0.93511,0.10344,3.6906,0.56448,-0.40754,0.75218,0.10346,-0.37737,-0.53789,0.57109,0.29602,-0.64821,-0.52805,0.34899,0.50146,0.61456,2.1785,-0.41,2.135,0.7426,0.3307,0.64542
CATMA2C47710,3.9021,3.7272,3.709,3.494,3.7557,3.7883,3.8697,3.4952,3.6365,3.6948,4.0954,3.7629,4.1282,3.6108,4.2769,3.3689,3.5232,3.7488,3.6237,4.0805,3.855,3.8724,4.2706,3.5584,3.9576,4.1324,3.857,3.6508,3.7609,3.7885,3.6256,3.8022,3.7189,3.7417,3.6357,3.6448,4.2841,3.8731,3.6047,3.7792,3.5703,3.8284,3.8098,3.8824,4.2441,3.6127,3.8253,3.529,3.6078,4.0917,3.6794,3.7977,3.8231,3.9369,3.6087,3.7634,3.6419,4.0052,3.7083,4.0191,3.3211,3.9133,3.74,4.0801,4.0999,3.6312,3.7747,3.7768,3.7977,3.9409,3.9423,3.6708,4.1773,3.666,3.8267,3.8832,4.0462,3.8007,3.3932,4.0945,3.9901,4.1036,4.1064,3.8178,3.7936,3.8638,4.3395,3.5859,3.5698,3.7885,4.4263,4.0292,3.6857,4.1197,4.0262,3.7753
CATMA3A13690,5.2022,5.6481,5.7765,4.8253,6.0581,6.2026,5.2711,6.4481,6.0929,6.3395,5.3806,4.9156,5.3634,4.5556,5.3547,5.5214,5.6947,5.9289,5.6269,5.5406,6.0508,5.8498,5.6275,5.4422,5.3293,5.7543,5.1577,6.3626,5.429,5.7245,5.7554,5.4575,5.2244,6.2312,6.0425,5.0317,5.4494,5.5252,5.5124,5.6588,5.0015,5.7454,5.6711,6.132,5.4789,6.1668,5.6978,5.113,4.3572,5.6177,5.9557,6.0099,5.2522,5.5598,6.2427,5.4703,5.4275,5.9159,5.3029,4.1094,5.927,5.9223,5.1257,5.3835,5.6579,5.5849,5.8674,4.9425,5.2144,5.5382,4.7165,5.5688,5.2766,6.4298,5.9438,5.7105,4.757,5.9097,5.3665,5.8336,5.8393,5.6104,5.4702,5.4028,5.0756,5.632,5.9963,5.7889,5.7521,5.5561,4.0685,6.3026,4.9628,6.176,5.7256,4.8529
CATMA3A15560,0.23073,0.32331,0.37953,0.081038,-0.33446,0.18495,0.86901,0.71363,0.33531,1.4741,0.32824,0.18869,-0.34772,0.97628,0.62455,-0.14645,0.42603,-0.00031328,0.92441,0.14199,0.25522,0.55583,0.10067,1.2818,0.64424,-0.24454,0.33039,0.25975,1.1023,-0.5464,0.62174,-0.15397,0.78478,0.2999,-0.063974,0.55156,0.44076,0.17798,0.61707,0.9308,0.19809,1.2378,0.26328,0.19767,0.069484,0.76748,0.45386,0.4495,0.050625,0.99311,-0.10988,-0.070507,0.46274,0.19475,0.36696,-0.16537,1.0566,0.94446,0.85272,1.194,-0.41335,0.17202,0.38729,0.65495,-0.32063,0.60186,0.24444,1.3128,0.48551,0.55998,1.8149,0.36494,0.10693,-0.19085,0.25082,-0.10628,-0.38432,0.50117,0.97923,-0.31536,-0.2634,-0.82767,0.70017,-0.0093473,0.27653,0.67773,0.40978,0.3315,0.5179,0.32044,2.9356,-0.51529,2.7438,0.4153,0.32022,0.74311
CATMA3A21390,-0.54603,-0.32262,-0.29966,-0.22463,-0.49654,-1.0552,-1.0705,-0.93928,-0.71247,-2.7228,-0.67849,-0.24868,-1.5015,-0.22486,-0.26215,-0.34298,-0.73168,-0.33699,-0.3455,-0.5349,-0.68784,-0.47506,-1.2541,0.86942,-0.14503,-2.0603,-0.35647,-0.67731,0.20243,-1.1881,-1.3828,-1.0471,-0.20157,-2.5492,-0.7862,-0.21715,-0.20583,-0.067758,-0.86589,-0.75509,-0.62777,-0.57176,-2.0996,-0.72894,-0.56391,-1.1054,-0.94172,-0.98805,-0.20763,-0.42764,-2.0142,-1.4079,-0.66326,-0.10354,-1.6284,-1.9413,-0.77001,-0.58492,-0.99846,-0.013285,-0.31205,-0.10665,-1.2396,-1.7556,-0.40454,-0.26631,-1.2694,-0.32263,-1.2293,-0.93683,0.97994,-1.8696,-0.26859,-0.25661,-0.33193,-0.83889,-0.25944,-0.63826,0.3387,-1.4443,-0.93123,-0.84915,-0.24606,-0.63109,-0.78621,-0.40802,-0.6463,-0.84319,-1.0379,-1.1471,1.9932,-1.3029,1.5286,-0.19754,0.018446,-0.55479
CATMA3A53880,3.917,3.6689,3.7213,3.8812,3.8253,4.4861,4.258,4.7926,4.9737,4.0869,3.2183,3.5812,3.408,3.3128,3.3915,4.1923,3.9122,4.0586,4.2707,4.3077,4.8926,4.1982,3.4817,3.5267,3.6952,3.6632,3.9304,4.0793,3.9499,4.2175,4.8303,4.9599,4.6336,3.8998,3.7932,3.8572,3.2167,3.7749,4.3971,4.0662,3.9241,4.6407,4.2837,4.9644,4.972,4.2565,3.8796,3.383,3.2382,4.1017,4.058,4.0423,3.6033,4.0774,5.141,4.9736,4.4372,3.8969,3.7386,3.3618,3.539,4.2588,3.4726,3.7424,3.5818,4.9159,4.3567,4.1291,4.1108,4.4035,3.1374,3.4675,3.762,3.9264,3.7319,4.1205,2.0915,4.4192,4.5049,4.5427,4.6205,3.4653,3.6017,3.3376,3.266,3.5561,3.4538,3.761,4.2013,4.1787,4.017,4.7773,3.748,4.4977,3.8685,3.7464
CATMA5A09500,6.2838,5.1076,6.6209,5.7153,5.9395,5.3601,4.2366,5.189,3.3074,4.8701,5.0357,5.0951,6.2843,5.691,5.5054,5.9949,5.0834,5.1484,4.5884,4.805,4.458,5.0816,4.7264,5.3661,5.0645,5.8293,5.2877,5.6602,5.3336,4.7329,4.843,5.1901,3.8431,4.683,5.7106,4.0774,6.5689,5.8061,5.3445,5.2905,3.837,4.6271,4.2277,4.6165,4.0081,4.5176,4.259,4.6363,4.8557,3.9828,5.9728,5.4698,5.4102,4.5802,5.0247,4.8967,4.0116,2.6636,5.4684,4.3454,6.6893,6.5624,6.1464,5.4444,5.3309,5.6682,5.5012,4.3162,2.9028,3.3906,4.6684,4.914,5.3601,5.5138,6.2191,5.8043,5.8165,5.1155,3.8681,4.9268,4.0232,6.1699,4.6327,5.7364,6.1934,6.7188,5.0755,5.7058,5.3703,4.3921,3.2108,4.9503,4.1003,4.8225,4.6701,4.7166
CATMA5A12680,1.7891,1.362,1.4303,0.61973,0.54124,1.2733,0.7775,0.66788,1.7338,0.63125,1.5852,0.91616,1.0712,0.81919,0.90152,0.77799,1.0835,0.32735,2.0868,0.5895,1.1445,0.64545,0.71776,0.33929,1.42,1.0729,1.4879,0.86379,0.95453,1.2928,0.97753,1.1738,0.79397,0.31563,0.86345,0.67595,1.3501,1.079,1.2034,1.2432,1.3696,1.1473,0.72528,0.57199,0.85965,0.65339,0.47614,0.43219,1.363,2.4026,0.98947,0.85204,1.2591,2.3151,1.6775,1.6555,1.0371,2.5586,-0.097071,0.91744,1.068,1.6819,1.0122,0.99911,0.75267,1.2195,0.42175,0.2554,0.4819,0.80025,0.44517,0.32442,1.9863,1.5019,1.2893,1.0669,1.6881,1.7581,1.6505,1.943,2.141,1.018,0.68207,0.84392,1.1452,1.009,1.1376,1.0572,1.9258,1.7039,0.10261,1.4549,0.94693,0.77945,0.049658,0.84178
CATMA5A14990,0.41247,0.51378,0.375,-0.24526,0.027658,-0.015345,-0.028278,-0.2643,0.3905,0.12299,0.94334,0.11482,0.50109,-0.55162,0.10768,-0.26433,-0.31064,-0.76526,1.0147,-0.73178,0.3323,-0.13657,-0.14013,-0.17878,0.31259,0.36723,0.55499,-0.2664,0.31862,0.60225,0.078919,0.18282,0.23014,-0.27835,0.16392,0.58131,1.052,0.062394,0.064929,-0.11918,-0.2167,-0.26018,-0.21649,-0.032523,-0.05763,-0.62775,-0.29148,0.13633,0.72715,1.535,0.08501,0.76137,0.54934,1.5163,-0.26612,0.58127,0.30339,1.8464,-0.17161,0.30309,-0.070279,0.28016,-0.036628,0.67464,0.34753,0.26499,-0.17856,-0.61162,-0.17941,-0.01017,0.21112,0.026389,0.64566,-0.39685,0.31403,-0.21637,1.1253,0.41434,0.77759,0.20421,0.70657,0.53273,-0.67276,-0.65656,0.6997,-0.06428,-0.13546,-0.15055,0.99804,1.4673,-0.47155,-0.056436,0.84609,-0.23068,-0.55114,0.68975
CATMA5A25890,-0.23072,0.82252,0.32512,0.13284,0.14406,0.005071,0.40953,-0.11252,-0.6367,-0.048073,0.21325,-0.046316,-0.35078,1.1023,-0.019882,-0.55825,-0.34621,0.1114,0.030302,-0.08142,0.19157,0.5152,-0.034952,0.20984,1.0547,0.4816,0.31078,0.14731,0.31811,-0.27275,-0.47217,-0.043207,0.29109,0.41192,-1.069,0.23357,-0.17453,0.015661,-0.26869,0.14587,0.19336,0.5926,-0.1583,0.61242,0.18635,0.01207,-0.21772,0.13986,1.9305,0.3349,0.62954,-0.04455,1.121,-0.14155,-0.33772,-0.42633,0.41828,-0.29794,-0.7107,1.4786,-0.37442,-0.45371,0.16175,-0.057764,-0.11803,-0.037838,0.25868,0.88605,0.33225,-0.24331,0.93084,-0.33266,0.9762,0.24755,0.30857,0.14661,1.8351,0.40313,0.45084,-0.52105,-0.31271,-0.37122,-0.28615,-0.0023692,-0.43072,-0.24417,-0.5184,0.13874,-0.32606,-0.1705,2.1396,-0.77657,2.3056,0.32096,0.29337,-0.034746
CATMA5A31940,4.4307,4.8735,4.7911,5.8201,5.9587,5.576,5.9084,5.849,5.2832,5.5423,5.0275,4.5254,4.5054,3.0696,5.6512,4.3986,4.9856,4.9222,4.951,4.5506,4.2185,4.3184,5.4783,4.4515,3.9397,5.6269,5.0988,6.1254,5.7446,5.6146,5.452,5.2047,5.3527,5.93,4.8931,5.5529,3.9876,4.1072,4.0583,5.4324,5.4681,4.392,4.5189,5.0629,4.9347,5.2165,4.6681,4.7428,4.1539,6.3376,5.353,6.2896,5.5844,5.1654,5.4391,5.3933,5.261,5.6974,4.5142,3.9851,3.569,4.0946,4.6662,5.1085,5.0319,4.4598,4.8672,3.7326,5.3032,5.0448,4.7771,4.2209,4.1886,4.284,5.4681,5.8331,4.7683,5.6614,5.3313,5.2017,5.1002,5.0642,4.4867,4.8576,4.1454,4.0971,5.0368,4.845,4.753,5.5496,2.9838,5.1394,3.342,4.1246,5.0121,4.618
```

Code proper (BHC is from Bioconductor):

```
library(argparse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(BHC)
library(parallel)
library(gplots)

#data prep and clustering, to get dendrograms etc as shown in plot
data = read.csv('input.csv',header=TRUE,row.names=1,check.names=FALSE)
genes = rownames(data)
samples = colnames(data)
data = data.matrix(data)
standardisedData = (data-mean(data))/sd(data)
samples = as.numeric(samples)
hc = bhc(standardisedData, genes, timePoints=samples, dataType='time-course', verbose=TRUE)

#the plotting proper
png('heatmap.png',width=6,height=6,units='in',res=300)
heatmap.2(standardisedData, Colv=NA, Rowv=hc, tracecol=NA, scale="none", col=brewer.pal(11,'RdBu'))
#heatmap.2(standardisedData, Colv=NA, Rowv=hc, tracecol=NA, scale="none", col=brewer.pal(11,'RdBu'), margins=c(3,10)) <- this fixes it on a single-case basis
dev.off()
```

Comment: I would take a quick look here for how to improve your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example You are likely to get a bit more traction if people can quickly reproduce your issue. These also look similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630956/main-title-at-the-top-of-a-plot-is-cut-off and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135982/how-to-stop-graphical-device-window-cutting-off-edges-of-plot

Comment: You can increase the `width` and `heigth` in the `png()`function or try to rearrange the layout of the hm using the `layout()` function. For help use `?layout()`. Or shrink the size of your text using `cex`.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the ideas, but let me stress the **AUTOMATIC** part. Sometimes the row labels will be short, sometimes they will be long. I can make it big enough on a case by case basis with the stuff you suggest, but then I get short labels and I end up with tons of dead space, or somebody puts in even longer labels and they still get clipped.

Comment: Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?   I don't think it will be easy, but I would probably try something that checked the length of the row labels and adjusted the `margins` parameter appropriately ... also, it is worth mentioning that `heatmap.2()` is from the `gplots` package (i.e., not part of base R).

Comment: Also, off-topic but there is a `scale()` function you can use for the  standarization you are doing above.

Comment: Krzysztof, we have dealt with this exact problem for these types of plots for some time now. Sample names can sometimes be excessively long (necessarily so), yet also variable. In the past I have tried to come up with some math tricks to count the number of char's in the longest name, then plug that into an algorithm to make a scaling factor for plot margins & such. But every algo. ends up eventually breaking later, requiring more manual intervention. In the end, we have resigned to leaving the names cropped for preliminary results &only beautifying plots manually for publication & formal use.

Comment: I think this is the method I've started with in the past, increasing complexity as needed to try and catch more and more edge-cases: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10490953/5359531

But as I mentioned, I've yet to find a solution using this method that successfully works 100% of the time and doesn't break the plots completely when a new edge case is eventually encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just giving it a fairly wide default margin, such that it should be clipped even with longer labels, e.g.:

```
heatmap.2(standardisedData, Colv=NA, Rowv=hc, tracecol=NA, scale="none", col=brewer.pal(11,'RdBu'), margins=c(14, 14))
```

The default margin size is `(5,5)`. The above increases the both the column and row margins, but you can increase just one or the other as well.

If you want to be more precise, you could try using `max(strwidth(rownames(standardisedData)))` to determine the amount of space needed by the largest label, and then convert that into the units expected by `par(mar=*)` (what `heatmap.2()` uses to specify plot margins.)

I think this should do the trick:

```
# determine margins to use
png('/tmp/trash', width=6,height=6,units='in',res=300)
plot.new()
margin_width = max(strwidth(rownames(standardisedData), units='inches')) * par('fin')[1]
dev.off()

#the plotting proper
png('heatmap.png',width=6,height=6,units='in',res=300)
heatmap.2(standardisedData, Colv=NA, Rowv=hc, tracecol=NA, scale="none", col=brewer.pal(11,'RdBu'), margins=c(5, margin_width))
dev.off()
```

Comment: the OP said in comments that they were looking for an *automatic* solution, i.e. something that would check the lengths of the row labels and adjust the margins accordingly ...

Comment: Just noticed that - thanks! Updated solution to suggest something along those lines. In practice though, I tend to find just setting the margin to ~10-14 results in a decent looking most of the time.

Comment: I ended up following something similar - I unearthed the font sizes that `heatmap.2()` uses for each of its axes and computed an estimate of a margin accordingly. Functional solution, but absolutely horrible in principle - I was, in all honesty, expecting someone to ride in and drop a simple function call that would do it automatically. Thanks for the feedback, guys, in particular to Ben Bolker for actually noticing what I was trying to convey and planting the seed for what came later.

Comment: Glad you got something working in place. Also, thanks for sharing the code snippet - this is the first time I've come across argparse and BHC, and both look like they could be pretty useful!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I don't even use argparse in the code snippet, I forgot to take it out from the library import bit. Good thing you found it useful though.