# R: ggplot2 x axis is cutted of at the edge

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I've produced a graph with the following code:

```
plot 
final <- plot + test_neu + geom_vline(xintercept=as.integer(as.POSIXct("2017-10-01")), col = "black", linetype=2)
         + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.6,1.9)) 
         + scale_x_datetime(expand = c(0, 0))
```

the graph looks like this:

[image]

If you are looking at the end of the x-axis, you are seeing, that the word "Okt" is a bit cutted. How I can handle this to display the full word ?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135982/how-to-stop-graphical-device-window-cutting-off-edges-of-plot

Comment: It doesnt help me :/